# Google Analytics pie chart and line graph showing opposite data for new and returning visitors

Tags: google-analytics, google-data-studio

The top and bottom graphs in the screenshot are talking about the same data.

[image: new and returning visitors problem from Google Data Studio]

But the pie chart is giving the opposite information than the line chart! Why does it occur?

Comment: Can you share your Google Data Studio setup for these graphs?  There may be something wrong with it.